# Is there a method that returns the current item of a sequence?

Tags: python, iterator, cycle, python-itertools

I have a list of class objects and I'm using `itertools.cycle()` to continually loop through it.

```
class Letter:
    def __init__(self,name):
       self.name = name
       self.att = 0
       self.att1 = 0
```

Now I create the list of class objects

```
letterList = [Letter('a'),Letter('b'),Letter('c'),Letter('d')]
```

Then I make a sequence with `itertools.cycle()` like so:

```
seqList = itertools.cycle(letterList)
```

Anytime I want to go to the next item in the sequence and assign a value to one of the items attributes:

```
next(seqList).att = 1
```

But what if I want to assign another value to a different attribute? Is there another iterator method that will allow me to call the current item in the sequence like:

```
thisItem(seqList).att1 = 7
```

Comment: That looks a bit funny. Could you provide a little more context?

Comment: You could just save the value:  `item = next(seqList); item.att1 = 1; item.att2 = 2;` for instance.

Comment: Just save a reference.

Comment: `next(seqList).__dict__.update({'attr1': 'value1', 'attr2': 'value2'})`

Comment: I don't think that will work as that creates another instance and it's inside the scope of a method. I need the same instance to be used throughout the cycle.

Comment: `x = next(seqList)` doesn't create a new instance of anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign next() to a variable and access that variable.

```
this_one = next(seqList)
this_one.attr = value
```

If you just plan to infinitely loop over the same items, you can use a for loop (a break step is useful for getting out eventually though!):

```
for item in itertools.cycle(seqList):
    item.attr1 = value1
    item.attr2 = value2
    if condition_met:
         break
```

Answer (score 0):

In most practical situations you simply use a variable, but just for fun, let's create a wrapper that would "remember" the last item (or N last items) for the given iterable:

```
from collections import deque

class recorded:
    def __init__(self, it, size=1):
        self.it = it
        self.buf = deque(maxlen=size)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        self.buf.append(next(self.it))
        return self.buf[-1]

    def last(self, n=0):
        return self.buf[-1-n]
```

Now you can write:

```
it = recorded(itertools.cycle(letterList))

it.next()

it.last().something = 11
it.last().somethingElse = 111
```

or even:

```
it = recorded(itertools.cycle(letterList), 2)

it.next()
it.last().something = 11

it.next()
it.last(1).something = penultimate
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution I found was:

```
next(seqList).att = 1
next(seqList)
next(seqList)
next(seqList)
next(seqList).att1 = 7
```

It's not pretty or elegant and it won't work very well for a larger set but it works for this situation and is very simple.